# How can you represent different kinds of functions in tikz/pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

[image]

I’m working on an article about function theory and I’m still trying to learn pgf (I know almost nothing about it and tikz) and I need to represent the functions in the xOy cartesian system. The functions should illustrate different proprietes like: strictly monotony, monotony, bounding on a certain interval, periodicity and so on. How can I represent functions easily and how can I construct auxilliary dotted lines like the ones in the figures? Or how to add + and - signs on the graphs? If you find it easier, please give me an article on learning to graph functions in pgf. Thank you so much!

Comment: Each of them is more or less trivial to do, but aren't you supposed to ask about how to do one and then do the rest yourself?

Comment: Sure. It is fine for me if you show me only how to do one of them (maybe the hardest one) and then I can try to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My example mainly depends on the functionalities of the tikz `math` library and performs most calculations explicitly.

For proper output the code needs five parameters: the function `f` to be plotted, the derivative `df` of the function, the maximum value of the y-axis `ymax`, the x interval `interval` and the number of points `N` where either a plus or a minus sign should be drawn.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

\tikzmath{
    \ymax = 1.6;
    \N = 28;
    \interval = 3/2*pi+0.2;
    \k = 2;
    %
    function f(\x) {
        sin(\k*\x*180/pi-90);
    };
    %
    function df(\x) {
        return(\k*cos(\k*\x*180/pi-90));
    };
    %
    \xmax = \interval/2+0.3;
    \xmin = -\xmax;
    \ymin = -\ymax;
}
\tikzset{
    sign/.style = {
        font=\tiny
    },
    minus sign/.style = {
        sign, text=red!90!black, anchor=south
    },
    plus sign/.style = {
        sign, text=green!60!black, anchor=north
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=graph]
        \draw[->] (0,\ymin) -- (0,\ymax) node[above]{$y$};
        \draw[->] (\xmin,0) -- (\xmax,0) node[right]{$x$};

        \draw[domain=-\interval/2:\interval/2, samples=100] plot(\x, {f(\x)});

        \path[clip] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax); 

        \tikzmath{
            for \i in {0,...,\N}{
                \x = \i/\N*\interval-\interval/2;
                \y = f(\x);
                \angle = atan(df(\x))-90;
                if f(\x) > 0.25 then {
                    { 
                        \path (\x,\y) -- ++(\angle:0.01) node[plus sign]{$+$}; 
                    };
                } else {
                    if f(\x) < -0.25 then {
                        { 
                            \path (\x,\y) -- ++(\angle-180:0.01) node[minus sign]{$-$}; 
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        }
    \end{scope}

    \draw ($(graph.south east)+(1,-1)$) rectangle ($(graph.north west)+(-1,1)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]